# How can I get Random Character from User Input and Store the Random Characters to Array?

Tags: java, arrays, function, random, java.util.scanner

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = new String[4];

    System.out.println("Type 3 Strings:");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);// User input
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) // used for loop for user input
        array[i] = input.nextLine(); // Assigned users value to array

    System.out.println("Your Strings are:");
    System.out.println(array[0]);
    System.out.println(array[1]);
    System.out.println(array[2]);
}
```

Now I want to find a random character set from `array`, the Random characters are also maximum (input string length-1). Then store the Random characters into another **Array**. What do I have to do next?.

Comment: user input <-> random. the user input isn't random, it's decided by what the user (wants to ) put in

Comment: Could you clarify your request, please?

Comment: Yes, when users input the Strings then array contain Strings. Now, how can I pick random characters from this array indexes?

Comment: Hi "0009laH", please check what I want to do in the whole program,
1. Scan 3 user input(Strings)
2. Store the user inputs into an Array.
3. Finding 3 random characters from this array.
4. But random characters aren't longer than user input character lengths. I mean, it will be input length-1.
5. Store these Random characters into another array.

Comment: You should edit and mention a test case to explain what you want to do. Also, essential details about the question should be included within the question and not in the comment section.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve a substring (with a random position and a random size) for each input string?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String[] array = new String[] {"125123412343","12123412343","12312341234"};
    String[] newArray = new String[3];

    Random random = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        int start = Math.abs(random.nextInt() % array[i].length());
        int end = Math.abs(random.nextInt() % (array[i].length() - start));
        newArray[i] = array[i].substring(start, end == 0 ? start + 1 : start + end);
    }

    for (String str : newArray)
        System.out.println(str);
}
```

How about now?

Comment: please check what I want to do in the whole program,
1. Scan 3 user input(Strings)
2. Store the user inputs into an Array.
3. Finding 3 random characters from this array.
4. But random characters aren't longer than user input character lengths. I mean, it will be input length-1.
5. Store these Random characters into another array.